# I want to call a certain parameter from my api

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having trouble calling a certain parameter from my api

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            news: [],
            loading: true,
            activeIndex: 0,
            description: '',
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props);
        let description = this.state.description;
        let regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
        let result = description.replace(regex, '');
        this.setState({ description: result });
```

I call him in the code like this

```
{item.description}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to it in the same way you did in your `componentDidMount` function:

```
{this.state.description}
```

Comment: When I do this, the text disappears from my flatList card

Comment: Can you post the code where you are actually using the state?  This will resolve to whatever you currently have stored in the state under ```description```.